# In poker, a flush is a hand where all five cards are of the same suit

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In poker, a flush is a hand where all five cards are of the same suit, but not in sequence. A straight is a hand that contains five cards of sequential rank in at least two different suits. A straight flush is a straight that is also a ush (or viceversa), that is, a sequence of five cards all of the same suit. Determine how many poker hands are:
1. Straight flushes
2. Straight
3. Flushes

Comment: Any thoughts?  For the first one, it isn't difficult to simply enumerate them (though you must decide whether $A2345$ is a straight or not).

Comment: Here's an oddball. I have also seen a royal flush treated separately from straight flushes. In other words, the solution did not consider a royal flush ($10JQKA$, same suit) to be straight flush. This is usually not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- For a straight, pick the face value of the low card (how many choices?) then pick the suit of each card (how many choices?)  The suits need not be the same here.
- For a flush, pick the suit (how many choices?) then pick the faces values of the cards (how many combinations?)  The face values of the cards need not be consecutive here.
- For a straight flush, pick the face value of the low card, then pick the suit.

Answer (score 0):

Straight flush is most restrive and easiest to quantify.
There are 4 suits, and the lowest valued card must be between A(low) and 10.
40 ways to make a straight flush.

Flush -- choose 5 of 13 cards * 4 suits

straight -- 10 cards for the lowest numbered card, 5 cards each can be one of 4 suits.

10*($4^5$)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

One of the answers is

$4 * C(13,5) – 40$